# Sort data Obtained from firebase i would like to sort to get newest data at the top(first)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
public void showList(){
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                    .setQuery(reference,Model.class)
                    .build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull final Model model) {
            ///What happen to data obtainied from fire base

            viewHolder.txtViewDescription.setText(model.getmName());

            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(model.getmImageUri())
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(viewHolder.tvImageView);

            viewHolder.tvImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GalleryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image_url",model.getmImageUri());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.image_view,parent,false);
            return  new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Emmanuel. I highly recommend checking out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are more likely to get help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, and why the code you have isn't accomplishing that.

Comment: Also note that [sorting firebase realtime database in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+descending+order) has been asked quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out those results.

Comment: layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setReverseLayout(true);
        ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);